# Stacking divs so they don't overlap

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

So I have a div centered in the middle of the page, which is a button and a search box, and another one underneath where the results of the search are supposed to show up. Everything works fine except that the search results appear behind the centered div.

I'd like them both to be stacked, so that when the results show up the top div moves up to make space. Any tips?

[Here's the jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/3f5ukxj0/1/).

**HTML**

```
<div class="container-fluid">


        <div class="row">
            <h4 class="title">Wikipedia Viewer</h4>
            <h4 class="port">by l-emi</h4>
        </div>

        <div id="aligner">
        <div class="row">

                <div id="centbox">
                    <div class="row">
                        <button type="button" class="butoni" id="randy">Random article</button>
                    <input type="text" name="search" placeholder="Or search!" class="butoni" id="searchy">
                    </div>
                </div>


        </div>

             <div id="resultati">
                <ul id="output">

                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>

</div>
```

**CSS for the top div:**

```
#centbox {
    overflow: auto;
    position: fixed;
    display: inline-block;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    z-index: 1;
    display: table;
    text-align: center;
}
```

**For the results area**

```
#resultati {
    background-color: #e3e1df;
    padding: 5px;
    margin-top: 3.5em;
    width: 50%;
    position: fixed;
    display: inline-block;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

**EDIT**

Fixed it! Changed `position: fixed;` to `position: absolute;` for both of them, then used `$('#centbox').css("top", "14%");` for the top div, and `$('#resultati').css("top", "16%");` for the results div.

[Updated jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/3f5ukxj0/4/).

Thanks all!

Comment: You should redo your design. You can't have this interaction between them with position fixed.

Answer (score 1):

After your output prepend, you can rewrite the top positioning, to push it to the top:

```
$('#centbox').css("top", "25%");
```

Comment: This worked, I did the same thing to the output box so they both moved up. Thanks! I guess my next question is, how do I make it possible for the page to scroll so the results aren't cut off?

Comment: Still, after 2-3 searches the results go behind the buttons, not below them.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to use this:

```
document.getElementById("centbox").style.top = "28%";
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
#output {
    position:absolute;
    background-color: #e3e1df;
    width:100%;
    margin-left: -5px;
}
```

Comment: That works in stopping them from overlapping, but doesn't move them up along the page.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need fixed position. I suggest you to vertical align the box with buttons and results.

If you gave no results, the box with the buttons will be in the middle; with just a result, the buttons will be still in the middle and you will still have the result you need (less visible blank page).